# php foreach loop with condition?

Tags: php

I want to loop only if points are greater than levels.
The result I want is "reward0"

The sum of points is 80 so greater than 50 but less than 100 so only one reward is required.

I tried like this but no luck.

```
$levels = [50, 100, 150, 200];
$points = 0;
$rewards = [];


foreach ($levels as $key => $level) {

    if($points >= $level) { 
        $rewards[] = 'reward' . $key;
    }

    // 20, 40, 60, 80
    $points += 20; 

}

return $rewards;
```

Comment: Please expand on `no luck`. Do you get an error? Is this in a function? `return` maybe should be `print_r`? Also not clear about `points is  80 so greater than 50 but less than 100`

Comment: Can you please explain the Logic clearer? I could not nderstand the logic.

Comment: In the above code, the execution will not enter into the `if condition`. That is, the `if` condition never becomes true. Thus `$rewards` array will be always empty.

Comment: @HarishST Thanks for your comment. How to make working?

Comment: First please explain what is your goal in a better way, so we can understand the issue and come up with a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If I understand your logic**, then this is what you want,

```
<?php
$levels = [50, 100, 150, 200];
$points = 0;
$rewards = [];
$points = count($levels) * 20;
$rewards = array_filter($levels, function($n) use ($points){ 
    return $n < $points;
});
print_r($rewards);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/3VJTR

Comment: If this is the logic, why we need to use `foreach`? We can simply discard `foreach` and replace it with `$points = count($levels) * 20;`. Right?

Comment: @HarishST Sir, **EDITED** :)

Comment: @AlwaysSunny Ha ha. I am just making sure there is a better way for OP. For him, it may be new. By the way, Thanks for the Edit Sir. ;) And you are the first one who understand the OP's question and that's great.